# Properly handle escape sequences in strings from argv in C++

Tags: c++, escaping, special-characters

I'm writing a larger program that takes arguments from the command line after the executable.  Some of the arguments are expected to be passed after the equals sign of an option.  For instance, the output to the log is a comma separated vector by default, but if the user wants to change the separator to a period or something else instead of a comma, they might give the argument as:

```
./main --separator="."
```

This works fine, but if a user wants the delimiter be a special character (for example: tab), they might expect to pass the escape sequence in one of the following ways:

```
./main --separator="\t"
./main --separator='\t'
./main --separator=\t
```

It doesn't behave the way I want it to (to interpret \t as a tab) and instead prints out the string as written (sans quotes, and with no quotes it just prints 't').  I've tried using double slashes, but I think I might just be approaching this incorrectly and I'm not sure how to even ask the question properly (I tried searching).

I've recreated the issue in a dummy example here:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

// Pull the string value after the equals sign
std::string get_option( std::string input );
// Verify that the input is a valid option
bool is_valid_option( std::string input );

int main ( int argc, char** argv )
{

    if ( argc != 2 )
    {
        std::cerr << "Takes exactly two arguments.  You gave " << argc << "." << std::endl;

        exit( -1 );
    }

    // Convert from char* to string

    std::string arg ( argv[1] );

    if ( !is_valid_option( arg ) )
    {
        std::cerr << "Argument " << arg << " is not a valid option of the form --<argument>=<option>." << std::endl;

        exit( -2 );
    }

    std::cout << "You entered: " << arg << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The option you wanted to use is: " << get_option( arg ) << "."  << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

std::string get_option( std::string input )
{
    int index = input.find( '=' );
    std::string opt = input.substr( index + 1 ); // We want everything after the '='
    return opt;
}

bool is_valid_option( std::string input )
{
    int equals_index = input.find('=');

    return ( equals_index != std::string::npos && equals_index < input.length() - 1 );
}
```

I compile like this:

```
g++ -std=c++11 dummy.cpp -o dummy
```

With the following commands, it produces the following outputs.

With double quotes:

```
/dummy --option="\t"
You entered: --option=\t
The option you wanted to use is: \t.
```

With single quotes:

```
./dummy --option='\t'
You entered: --option=\t
The option you wanted to use is: \t.
```

With no quotes:

```
./dummy --option=\t
You entered: --option=t
The option you wanted to use is: t.
```

My question is: **Is there a way to specify that it should interpret the substring \t as a tab character (or other escape sequences) rather than the string literal "\t"?**  I could parse it manually, but I'm trying to avoid re-inventing the wheel when I might just be missing something small.

Thank you very much for your time and answers.  This is something so simple that it's been driving me crazy that I'm not sure how to fix it quickly and simply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The escape sequences are already parsed from the shell you use, and are passed to your command line parameters array `argv` accordingly.

As you noticed only the quoted versions will enable you to detect that a `"\\t"` string was parsed and passed to your `main()`.
Since most shells may just skip a *real TAB character* as a whitespace, you'll never see it in your command line arguments.

But as mentioned it's mainly a problem of how the shell interprets the command line, and what's left going to your program call arguments, than how to handle it with c++ or c.

> My question is: **Is there a way to specify that it should interpret the substring \t as a tab character (or other escape sequences) rather than the string literal "\t"?** I could parse it manually, but I'm trying to avoid re-inventing the wheel when I might just be missing something small.

You actually need to scan for a string literal

```
"\\t"
```

within the c++ code.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was sort of afraid that this would be the case, but knowing that it's the case, I can work with that.